# PHP MySql Time slot search

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to find the free timeslots of duration 60 min between 9:00 and 17:00 from a table having three columns (user_id, start_time, end_time), but somehow unable to get it work.

I've only one table 'timing' where I'm storing all booked slots. Assume all entries are for a day only.

```
Select 
  a.id,
  a.end_hour AS `Free time Start`,
  IFNULL(la.start_hour,a.end_hour) AS `Free Time End`,
  IFNULL(TIMEDIFF(la.start_hour, a.end_hour),'00:00:00') AS `Total Free Time`
FROM timing AS a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM timing LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615) AS la
    ON la.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM timing where (id > a.id AND user_id = a.user_id) LIMIT 1)
WHERE a.user_id = 2;
```

With this, I'm able to find all free slots in between actually used slots. I need help on two points

1. How to include start and end time of day (9:00 and 17:00, respectively). So, if first occupied slot starts at 10:00, 9:00-10:00 is also a free slot

2. How to split free time in fixed duration slots (say 1 hour)

Thanks!

Comment: maybe I do this the old fashioned way but what if you "downloaded" the data to your programming language (I assume your using PHP) and then filtering it with that? I am assuming your only going to be using 1 day at a time so a single day will only have 8 slots anyway right?

Comment: For your first question. You can define it in your where clause.`WHERE endhour < 17:01 AND starthour > 08:59`.

Comment: @Adsy2010: It's possible that I've 12:30 - 2:30 as used slot.. Unable to handle this kind of scenario. Three solts 9-10, 10-11 and 11-12 should be shown